# If all iPads have the same 768x1024 screen size, what is the "scale" for?

Tags: ios, ipad, graphics

The simulator says that all iPads have the same size (768 x 1024).
Is that correct?

Since the devices' sizes are the same, is it possible to place a 100x100 rect and expect it to look the same? Or will it not look the same, because of the scale?

Please explain to me what scale is used for: do I have to adjust my rect size to account for the scale?

Comment: What "scale" are you talking about?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand in Apple's documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS uses an abstract display scale: points. A point is 1/72 of an inch.

The mini iPads cheat. Points are actually smaller than 1/72 of an inch on the mini, but for the purposes of this discussion we'll ignore that. The iPad mini still uses points for rendering. The resulting images are smaller however.

iOS also has a scale property. The scale property tells how many physical pixels there are in a point. Retina iPads have a scale of 2. So if you draw a 1 point by 1 point rectangle on a retina iPad, it will actually be drawn using 2 x 2 screen pixels. Ignoring the mini, the rectangle will appear the same size on retina and non-retina devices. Each point will be rendered as 1 pixel on a non-retina device, and 2x2, or 4 pixels on a retina device.

Where retina devices gain an advantage is things like anti-aliased curves, diagonal lines, and continuous tone images like gradients and full-color pictures. Those all render content at the same scale on retina and non-retina devices, but there is more detail on retina devices. Anti-aliasing is done at the pixel level, so diagonal lines and curves look smoother and more natural. This gives a big benefit for text, which looks crisper and better on a retina device. The text will be the same display size on both a retina and non-retina device, but since the retina device has 4 times as many pixels it is able to render the text at higher resolution.

(Photographs do not magically gain more resolution on retina devices. You are supposed to provide both non-retina and retina versions of images, and name the retina images with the "@2x" suffix.) So you might have an image "flower.png". You'd also provide "flower@2x.png". In your code you'd use the code

UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageWithName: "flower"];

(The system assumes a suffix of ".png" if you don't specify one.)

On retina devices, the system will check for a file "flower@2x.png". If it finds it, it will use that, and assume that it contains 2 time as many pixels in each dimension as the non-retina image. If it can't find a retina image, it will use the non-retina image and save each image pixel into 4 screen pixels, creating an image that isn't as crisp and detailed. The same goes for a non-retina device. Those devices simply ignore the @2x version of the image and load the regular image.

#### iPhone

In the world of iPhone there's also the iPhone 6 plus, whose screen has 3x3 pixels per point. If you support iPhone and iPad then you need to provide images at non-retina resolution, @2x, and also @3x. Note that if you are iPhone-only, you no longer need to provide non-retina images, since all iPhones able to run the last several iOS versions are retina devices. The iPhone 3Gs was the last non-retina iPhone. It can only run iOS <= iOS 6, which most developers no longer support.

Comment: So it will look the same on both retina and none retina devices, but  retina has more higher resolution??

Comment: Yes, that's correct. (Again, ignoring the iPad minis, where the image will be smaller due to the smaller screen)

Comment: Note that the display size on the iPad pro is MUCH larger. It's a whole different animal.